# How do I get a drop down menu with dynamic values in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form with two fields:

1. Date field - With a jQuery calendar widget that lets me choose a
   date
2. Time field - A drop down menu with times from 9:00 AM to 5:30 PM at
   30 minute intervals (9:00AM, 9:30AM etc)

Now, based on the date picked by the user in the date field, I'd like to restrict times. For example if the user makes the choice of tomorrow, at 2:00PM today, I'd like to restrict the times to only after 2:00 PM tomorrow. I want there to be a 24 hour gap. How would I go about enforcing complex rules like these when dealing with Django forms? I read in a blog that I could use an if condition in the forms.py file to restrict the options, but I want to keep this to the client side. How would I achieve this? This is what I have so far.

My Template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
{% load staticfiles %}

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/datepair.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.datepair.js' %}"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<script>
var dateToday = new Date();
      $( function()
      {
        $( "#id_pickup_date" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            maxDate: "+2w",
            minDate: "+1"
        });

      });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

My Form:

```
class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    pickup_date = forms.CharField(label='Enter Date', max_length=100)
    # pickup_time = forms.CharField(label='Enter Time', max_length=100)
    # days = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 32)])
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('1', '9:00AM'),
        ('2', '9:30AM'),
        ('3', '10:00AM'),
        ('4', '10:30AM'),
        ('5', '11:00AM'),
        ('6', '11:30AM'),
        ('7', '12:00PM'),
        ('8', '12:30PM'),
        ('9', '1:00PM'),
        ('10', '1:30PM'),
        ('11', '2:00PM'),
        ('12', '2:30PM'),
        ('13', '3:00PM'),
        ('14', '3:30PM'),
        ('15', '4:00PM'),
        ('16', '4:30PM'),
        ('17', '5:00PM'),
        ('18', '5:30PM'),
    )

    my_choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

Comment: I use [django-angular](http://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html) for things like this, you can set ng- attributes in the widget attributes.

Comment: @HaifengZhang Yes, I already went over that blog before I posted here, but I want the dynamic stuff to be implemented on the client side, not within the server.